# Trim() is not working

Tags: java, trim

```
while(rs.next()) {              
    value = rs.getString(1).trim().split(",");
    mineral.addAll(Arrays.asList(value));
}
```

Here the value of `rs.getString(1)` is given below.

> "Dimension Stone, Kankar, River Sand, "

this value is trimed using `trim()` and `split` using `split(",")` and assign to the array `value`.
Here my problem is `trim()` do not trim the spaces in the 
`String`.

Can anyone suggest the reason for this and solve my problem?

Comment: whats spaces do you want to trim? If you are trying to trim spaces in between text if will definitely not work. Because trim() just trim spaces from beginning and end of a string or text

Comment: The reason is that's not what it does:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: yea that why it will really don`t trim() spaces in between

Comment: (Note that's not really a great way to use a relational database.)

Comment: Rule #1 - if a standard Java class/method is not behaving as expected, the chances are 99.99% that your expectations are wrong, not the class/method.  Read the javadoc carefully.  Read it a second time to make sure you understood it.

Answer (score 4):

The `trim` function does not remove intra-sentence spaces, it only removes the whitespace characters at *either end of the string*. If you want all the strings trimmed then you need to invoke the function for each one.

```
String[] values = rs.getString(1).split(",");
for(String value : values) {
    mineral.add(value.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to split the string like this

```
value = rs.getString(1).trim().split(" *, *");
```

Answer (score 0):

trim() will just remove leading and trailing spaces and not the spaces within the string.
Do you wish to remove space between 'Dimension Stone'?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that, if you wish to use [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) then you can go with **Perception** answer or you can use `replace(""," ")`

for example using `replace(" ","")`

```
 String[] values = rs.getString(1).replace(" ", "").split(",");
```